# onShowFileChooser doesn't fire if permissions wasn't granted

Tags: android

My webView application is asking for permissions when user taps on file upload

```
        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback < Uri[] > valueCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();

            Log.d("LOG", "Triggered 1");

            if (fileChooserCallback != null) {
                fileChooserCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }

            fileChooserCallback = valueCallback;

            String[] permissions = new String[] {
                android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            };

            Log.d("LOG", "Triggered 2");

            if (!hasPermissions(context, permissions)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissions, PERMISSION_CAMERA_WITH_STORAGE);
            } else {
                startPictureSelectionActivity();
            }

            return true;
        }


        private boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String...permissions) {
            for (String permission: permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CAMERA_WITH_STORAGE) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    startPictureSelectionActivity();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION) {
                if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    locationCallback.invoke(locationOrigin, true, true);

                }
            } else {
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
        }
```

And upload works fine if users agrees to give requested permissions, but if he doesn't, application just doesn't react (just nothing happens, log is empty) on upload tap anymore until user restarts an app. What is the problem?

I need what on second tap app would request permissions again, and so until users agrees with requested permissions. For example Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox both opens recent files if user denied all permissions, and on next attempt to upload a file ask for permissions again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added intent on permission denying, now works fine, identical to Mozilla Firefox work.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CAMERA_WITH_STORAGE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startPictureSelectionActivity();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, FILECHOOSER_RESULT_CODE);
        }
    } else if (requestCode == PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationCallback.invoke(locationOrigin, true, true);
        }
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Override `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, check if permission was granted and then call `startPictureSelectionActivity();` inside it.

More details in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Comment: I already have that code, problem is not with photo selection, problem is that onShowFileChooser doesn't ask for permissions on second tap if on first permissions was denied.